Invert cone representation in mplstereonet
I'm using mplstereonet to represent data in a stereonet. One of the features I want to show is the blind zone around a borehole. Traditionally, this is represented by a cone in a stereonet, as shown in the following image.

I used the following code:
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplstereonet
import numpy as np

fig, ax = mplstereonet.subplots(projection='equal_angle', figsize=(3,3), dpi=150)
ax.cone(bearing=250, plunge=60, angle=75,alpha=0.3)
ax.grid(kind = 'polar', alpha = 0.5) 
ax.set_longitude_grid_ends(80)
plt.xticks(np.arange(-2*np.pi,2*np.pi,np.pi/18))
plt.yticks(np.arange(0,100*np.pi/180,10*np.pi/180))    
ax._polar.set_position(ax.get_position())

But I would like to invert the cone representation, so that the blue area is not colored and the uncolored area is blue.
The following image shows what I would like to achieve:

I tried the following option, where I'm only able to partially 'invert' the cone representation:
ax.cone(bearing=250, plunge=60, angle=75,alpha=0.3, bidirectional=False)


And also
ax.cone(bearing=250, plunge=60, angle=105,alpha=0.3, bidirectional=False)


But I've not been able to have the inside of the cone left white and the outside colored.
Any hints?
